# Fixed UISearchBar using UISearchController - Not using header view of UITableView

Tags: ios, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

Is it possible to put UISearchBar of UISearchController somewhere other than header view of UITableView?

In the [apple's sample code for UISearchController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/TableSearch_UISearchController/Introduction/Intro.html), following is used.

```
[self.searchController.searchBar sizeToFit];
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar;
```

Is it possible to position searchBar somewhere else? 
Say we want to implement a fixed UISearchBar like the one used in contacts app.
I've tried this but the searchBar doesn't appear at all.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can place the UISearchBar of UISearchController in the navigation bar so that it remains fixed

```
self.searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = NO;
self.searchController.searchBar.searchBarStyle = UISearchBarStyleMinimal;

// Include the search bar within the navigation bar.
self.navigationItem.titleView = self.searchController.searchBar;

self.definesPresentationContext = YES;
```

Comment: I was about to rip out the `SearchController` again for a manually managed `UISearchBar` before reading your answer, thanks for saving me a bunch of time!

Answer (score 9):

Create One uiview and added searchController.searchbar inside this view.
After that add this view in your viewController.view. above the table view.

then it will not scroll.

```
   var viewTemp = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0.0, 64.0,320.0, 44))
   viewTemp.addSubview(self.searchController.searchBar)
   self.view.addSubview(viewTemp);
```

Comment: This does seem to be the solution for when you don't want to make the UISearchBar the header view of a UITableView. Thanks!

Comment: @AndrewR In that case. just do tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar

Comment: This works except it messes up section index scrolling :(

Comment: What's the point of the temp view? Why not just add the UISearchBar directly?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of directly keeping UISearchBar on top of UITableView. **Put the UISearchBar inside a view.**[image]